# How to use optional @State variable with binding parameter in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use an optional `@State` variable with a TextField. This is my code:

```
struct StorageView: View {
    
    @State private var storedValue: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type a value", text: $storedValue)
        }
        
    }
}
```

When I use this code, I get the following error:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'`

I have tried the following code for both the values to be optional, but nothing seems to work:

```
TextField("Type a value", text: $storedValue ?? "")
```

```
TextField("Type a value", text: Binding($storedValue)!)
```

How would I go about using an optional `@State` variable with a binding? Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Actually you are passing optional value to Binding variable. You need to change your declaration as follow `@State private var storedValue = ""`

Comment: If you search for this error on so you will find many answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about using an optional @State variable with a binding? Any help with this is appreciated.

It looks like you *are* using an optional state variable with a binding. You get an error because `TextField`'s initializer expects a `Binding<String>` rather than a `Binding<String?>`. I guess you could solve the problem by adding another initializer that accepts `Binding<String?>`, or maybe making an adapter that converts between `Binding<String?>` and `Binding<String>`, but a better option might be to have a good think about why you need your state variable to be optional in the first place. After all this string something that will be displayed in your UI -- what do you expect your `TextField` to display if `storedValue` is nil?